# $\operatorname{Span} (S) + \operatorname{Span} (T) = \operatorname{Span} (S) \Rightarrow \operatorname{Span} (T) = \{\mathbf{0}\}.$ Is this true?

Tags: vector-spaces

I am proving one corollary of replacement theorem, I have come to a situation when $S\cup T$ and $S$ both generates a vector space $V$. Thus, I wrote
 $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Span}  (S\cup T)  &= \operatorname{Span}  (S)\\
 \Rightarrow \operatorname{Span} (S) + \operatorname{Span} (T) &= \operatorname{Span} (S).
\end{align}$$
Does this imply $\operatorname{Span} (T) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$, how can we prove or disprove this?

Comment: What if $T=S$? $\quad$

Comment: Thanks Eevee Trainer to aware me that I can use this, as I know this typesetting language.

Comment: -lulu, Yess, now I got this. If T=S or infact T is subset of S, even then that equation holds, so my claim that T = 0 is false.

Answer (score 2):

We can have $\operatorname{Span}(S)+\operatorname{Span}(T)=\operatorname{Span}(S)$ whenever $T\subseteq S$. Thus, as long as $S\neq\{0\}$, we can choose $\{0\}\subsetneq T\subseteq S$, which disproves the title claim.